# Intents on dialogflow not updating on actions on google

Tags: python, node.js

"Request contains an invalid argument.
Your app must have at least one action for locale hi"

Getting this error

Comment: Welcome to SO ;) Please read this article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This would include a proper description of what you are trying to achieve, your code (or the relevant snippets) as well as your efforts showing what you have tried so far and possible error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you try to send a request in Hindi (locale hi) to DialogFlow. According to the error you do not have any actions for the agent which handles the request. Things which could solve your problem are:

1. Check whether you really want to handle requests using Hindi. 
      It might be that you set the locale to hi by mistake.
2. Check whether actions exist for the agent or [define them](https://developers.google.com/actions/dialogflow/define-actions).

Comment: Hey man i am unable to get responses on AOG, could you please help me out ?

Comment: "agentToAssistantJson": "{ \"responseMetadata\": { \"status\": { \"code\": 10,\"message\": \"Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of empty speech response\",\"details\": [{\n \"@type\": \"type.googleapis.com/google.protobuf.Value\", \"value\": \"{\\\"id\\\":\\\"692a3fb3-8279-4a76-a5a4-5accc9cae07b\\\",\\"timestamp\\":\"2018-11-19T04:36:34.913Z\",\"lang\":\"en-us\",\"result\":{},\\"alternateResult\\":{},\\\"status\\":{\\\"code\\\":200,\\\"errorType\\\":\\\"success\\\"},\\\"sessionId\\\":\\\"ABwppHE9zykWsY992-xBjZYp9Z2RnaX2XsdzKTn9CdIJUQGKXwZh72Xz1XXBvMrZF8XwR3WH_JxyRQ\\\

Comment: If the answer helped you please mark it as answer, thanks :) For new questions please make a new topic. That way others can easier find the question and answer if they have similar problems. :)

Comment: The most important part of the error seems to be 'failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of empty speech response'. My guess would be that DialogFlow sends an empty response to some input from you to AppResponse. So, make sure that DialogFlow works when sending input text and getting output text. Then you can add functionality on top of that! 

If this answer does not help, please open a new question on this site.

Comment: Well i am sorry too say that it wasn't that helpful, it could be really helpful if you add some more details, I have posted it as a formal question and given more data, please do check it out

Comment: I have posted a formal question regarding my problem with screenshots and explanations, please do look into it and help me out